# Stacking a table with an image on mobile using html/css

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Very new to all this and playing around with having a two column button (of sorts) that will feature a coloured background with some text on one side and an image (which will also be a link) on the other.

I also want this to stack on mobile. I have had some success using other snippets of code found on here, but I can't get it quite right - mainly the left side of my 'button' doesn't fill the whole side.

There's probably a really simple solution, but I can't seem to find it right now!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  align-content: center;
}

.row {
  max-width: 280px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/e31ffc7f9716689ceb3f1e8be/images/65235be8-d229-4c50-801e-36f5bccbf429.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use flex rather than floats (the advantage is you get equal height columns):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
}

.column>img {
  width: 100%;    /* just makes the image resize to the column */
  display: block; /* removes space below image */
}

.row {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: flex;   /* use flex instead of floats */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;  /* change direction of flex to columns at small screen size */
  }
  .column {
    width: 100%;              /* make column full width */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/e31ffc7f9716689ceb3f1e8be/images/65235be8-d229-4c50-801e-36f5bccbf429.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thank you! This seems to have done the trick for now - now to play with making that whole left side a link and positioning the text. Can hopefully work that out for myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can spend a couple of hours fiddling around with various html/css settings, or you can take 20 mins and do a tutorial that will cover this and several other aspects.

For wizardly easy mobile stuff, take a look at Bootstrap. Here's a [brilliantly speedy tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) that will get you started. Basically, Bootstrap involves just a few files that you need to reference at the top of your page and voila, you have some pretty cool functionality. If you reference [these three files](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp) (reproduced below) at the top of each page, you will have access to all the super-easy Bootstrap wonderfulness that will automatically handle the different screen sizes for you.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also, another great thing to check into is Flexbox - [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc) is worth every second of the 28 minutes.

Finally, look into CSS Grid. Sorry, I don't have a good reference for you but its easy to find some good tuts on that.